# Angular modal dialog and http request

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api, dialog

I have a web API with endpoint to create new directory another endpoint to rename existing directory. In angular I have input of directory name with modal dialog. Is it better to send http request to web API inside modal dialog or close dialog and return name and then send request and if there are validation error or http request unsuccessful open dialog again and display error?

Comment: I'd keep the request sent from dialog - it handles the user's action and is expected to show some warning/error if the action cannot be completed: server unresponsive, error on server side, or even using a forbidden/taken name for a directory and such. If it's just a hiccup on server side, it's better for UX to keep the dialog open amd display the error, so user can possibly try to submit the same form again without having to start the dialog again after being returned to main page.